# Mouseover Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, mouseover

I have the following problem: I am using the selenium webdriver with Java and want to extract all links of a webpage. Some links are generated on demand. That means with a mouseover on the menulinks there will be generated more links. When I load the page these links are not there.

I tried to first extract the menu-navigation-links, do a mouseover and then ask the driver for the "new" links. But it seems that there a no "new" links.

```
WebElement mainNavi = element.findElement(By.className("navigation"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
List<WebElement> menuHoverLinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
menuHoverLinks.addAll(mainNavi.findElements(By.cssSelector("a")));

for (WebElement menuHoverLink : menuHoverLinks) {
  Actions hoverOverRegistrar = actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
  hoverOverRegistrar.perform();
}
```

First: Is my idea right? Is it possible to do so? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the links are generated dynamically then they may not exist initially. You should use [Implicit Waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) after you click on the menu to allow the webpage to load up the new content before trying to query them.

Instead of using `Actions`, consider using `WebElement`, which supports clicking.

For example, You might say something like

```
// do an implicit wait until the menu is fully loaded
List<WebElement> elmts = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a"));
for (WebElement elmt : elmts) {
    elmt.click();
}
```

Comment: But thanks for this hint, so this is kind of the right answer ;)

Comment: Consider putting up an answer that solves the problem.

Comment: I didnt figured it out exactly but it seems that Actions are not right in my case. Now I am trying to use Java Robot in order to simulate mouse interactions.

Comment: Given your code, you should not need to use robots or actions if you're just interacting with the DOM. See edit.

Comment: The DOM is changed by the user with hovering over specific links. The hover will generate more links which I need to get afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static String[] links = null;
    private static int linksCount = 0;  
    public static void main(String[] args){

     driver.get("basic url");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    List<WebElement> all_link_webpage=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    linksCount = all_link_webpage.size();
    System.out.println(linksCount);
    links= new String[linksCount];
    for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
    {
    links[i] = all_link_webpage.get(i).getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(all_link_webpage.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
    }
  }
```

This will help you to make a count of all links in the webpage and print the links in the console. i hope it can helpful. Moreover am not sure about mouse hover links.. :) thankq.